# Couldn't match expected type Person with actual type IO ()

Tags: haskell, types, io

I have started learning Haskell, and reading Learn You Haskell. Chapter 8 dealing with "making our own types and typeclasses" and I have a error message which is a problem for me. Probably the solution is a tiny thing, but I couldn't find it, so please reveal the hint and or help me out an explanation.

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , lastName :: String  
                     , age :: Int  
                     } deriving (Eq, Show, Read)  

mikeD = Person {firstName = "Michael", lastName = "Diamond", age = 43}  

main = print $ read "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}" :: Person
```

This is the error message I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `Person' with actual type `IO ()'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    print
    $ read
        "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}" ::
      Person
In the expression:
  do { print
       $ read
           "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}" ::
         Person }
In an equation for `main':
    main
      = do { print
             $ read
                 "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}" ::
               Person }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try adding parens around the read statement.

Comment: `print (read "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}" :: Person)` works. I hope someone will explain why it is not equivalent to your `$` version ! I guess the scope of type annotation is syntactic.

Comment: hi Jean-Baptiste, thanks, and yes, works, Tamas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
main = 
  print $ read "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}" :: Person
```

is parsed as

```
main = 
  (print $ read "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}") :: Person
```

whereas you've meant

```
main = 
  print (read "Person {firstName =\"Michael\", lastName =\"Diamond\", age = 43}" :: Person )
```

Comment: hello Zeta, thanks for the comment, the example is clear, Tamas